# Norm inequality in Sobolev space $H^s$ as algebra for $s>n/2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $n\in \mathbb N^*$ and let $s>n/2$. Then the Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ is a multiplicative algebra included in $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and we have 
$
\Vert uv\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}\le C(s,n)\Vert u\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}\Vert v\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}.
$

I believe that we also have
$$
\Vert uv\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}\le C'(s,n)\bigl(\Vert u\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\Vert v\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}
+\Vert v\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)}\Vert u\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}\bigr).
$$
I found an answer in J.-Y. Chemin book MR1688875, Corollary 2.4.1.

Comment: What is J.-Y. Chemin book MR1688875 (why are referencing the book like this)? You might want to provide a link to the book.

Comment: MR1688875  is the MathReview number on MathSciNet.